# Is there a way to add numeric values together in a string without looping?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a string say: '212'. This string is dynamically generated.

Is there a way to add these numbers together without looping?

If needed, I will loop and add the values; but after researching the [Adobe Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html) I wanted to see if there was a better way.

Thank you

Comment: If the string is dynamically generated, look for a way to add the digits up while generating the string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure.. just for fun.

```
digits = 212;
sum = arraySum(listToArray(digits, ""));
writeOutput(sum);
```

Run script above: http://trycf.com/gist/3677b4e7d17d4fbac37d/acf

Comment: To grab single digits, my preference is: `arraySum(Rematch("\d", theString))`